# PHP Warning: ldap_mod_replace(): Modify: Server is unwilling to perform in

Tags: php, ldap

Below is my code but getting an error as:
`PHP Warning:  ldap_mod_replace(): Modify: Server is unwilling to perform in`

**Here is the code:**

```
$ip = "10.60.0.12";
$ldaps_url = "ldaps://$ip";
$port = 636;
$ad = ldap_connect($ldaps_url, $port)

$ad->set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$ad->set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$b = $ad->bind($config['ad']['binddn'], $config['ad']['bindpassword']);     
$newPassword = "fssfgds^^&&";

$userdata["unicodePwd"] = $newPassword;   
$userdata["pwdLastSet"] = - 1;
$userdata["userAccountControl"] = 512;
$result = $ad->mod_replace($dn, $userdata);
```

Not sure what went wrong in above code, could anyone please look into this and tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Server is unwilling to perform` means that you're not binding as a user with sufficient rights to perform that action.

It's a credentials/access control issue with LDAP not necessarily your code.